# Publish is producing .nuget package instead of a class library + dependencies

Tags: c#, publish, portable-class-library

I've created some C# class libraries which are intended to be used as dynamic plugins for a console application.  I thought I could use the Publish task in Visual Studio to create a folder containing a Release assembly + dependencies but instead, it is packaging the project assembly into a nuget package!

How do I get a simple output of assemblies + dependencies out of my class library?

Here is my .csproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
        <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
        <Platforms>AnyCPU</Platforms>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\..\MyService.PluginBase\MyService.PluginBase.csproj">
            <Private>false</Private>
            <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
        </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

My publish settings are as follows:

- Configuration: Release | Any CPU
- Target Framework: net5.0
- Target Runtime: Portable
- Deployment mode: Framework-dependent

Comment: Once you have output your assemblies, how do you plan to reference them in other projects?

Comment: Hi Luke, the plan was to drop them into a folder where they will be discovered and loaded in at runtime by the plugin system.  This works if I copy across the "bin" output but I thought that publishing a class lib would allow me to reduce the file count by creating a "single file assembly".

Comment: I guess just dotnet build is what you want then? Makes sense that dotnet publish creates a nuget package as a class lib would normally be consumed using a nuget install.

Comment: Thanks @Luke.  I guess I've assumed Publish is always the "right" route to production but I guess I've missed the simple (and obvious, now that you've said it!) solution. Thanks.